# redirect in rails 4 with different options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, parameters, controller

I have this instance for user show page when request comes let's say from user index page:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

But when request comes from conversation controller I use use this

```
redirect_to user_path(@conversation.recipient_id)
```

Still, if I use this way I get an error message that: Couldn't find User with 'id'=16, which id belongs to the given conversation that the 2 users (id:1 and id:2) have together. So it's finding the conversation id with the params[:id] and I don't find what statement I should use to resolve this. I tried this:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) unless @user
```

and a few others but didn't work out.

user.rb:

```
has_many :conversations, foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy
```

conversation.rb:

```
belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
```

application_controller

```
  def set_conversation
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) if @user?
    if Task.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?
      if Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?
        @conversation = Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).first
        @reciever = interlocutor(@conversation)
        @messages = @conversation.messages
        @message = Message.new
        @uploader = @message.mfile
        @uploader.success_action_redirect = messagefilecreation_conversation_url(@conversation.id)
      end
    else
      redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
    end
  end
```

conversation_controller

```
  before_action :set_conversation, only: [:messagefilecreation]

  def messagefilecreation
    @uploader.key = params[:key]
    Message.create(conversation_id: @conversation.id, user_id: current_user.id, key: @uploader.key )
    redirect_to user_path(@conversation.recipient)
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the associations in the `User` and `Conversation` models?

Comment: Posted. I guess the problem is when there is the user given by @conversation.recipient then it should ignore User.find(params[:id])

Comment: Would you also post the entirety of your conversation controller?

Comment: Is the set_conversation method a before_action hook for the messagefilecreation method?

Comment: Yeah, exactly as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is provided, it seems like the ID 16 (in this case) is coming from the ID of conversation, rather than recipient ID.  The method is being exited on the `@user = User.find(params[:id])` line with the not found error.

This is because you're using the ID of the conversation in `@uploader.success_action_redirect = messagefilecreation_conversation_url(@conversation.id)`, which in turn provides that same id in `params[:id]` during the followup call to `messagefilecreation` once the user submits the form.

I would recommend splitting `set_conversation` into 2 methods in the child controllers, and allow them to determine the `@conversation` themselves, since the shared `set_conversation` method doesn't seem to be advantageous given the differences between the 2 endpoints and their respective purposes.

Comment: Conversation/task/user are displayed on the same page (user/show), so to be able get to the user/show page I have to define all the instances. I don't see how I could split.

Comment: The method that exists presently is fine for the users#show page.  However, `@conversation` should be set using `Conversation.find params[:id]` for the `messagefilecreation` method, since the ID provided is that of the conversation, not the user.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either. Can you a bit elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think your controllers are a bit weird.

I'd do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users
resources :conversations do
   resources :messages
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @users = User.all
   end

   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @conversations = @user.conversations
   end
end

#app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @conversation = Conversation.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @conversation = Conversation.find params[:conversation_id]
      @messages = @conversation.messages.all
   end

   def show
      @conversation = Conversation.find params[:conversation_id]
      @message = @conversation.messages.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

The problem you have is you're not harnessing the *object orientated* nature of Rails, thus leading you to call all sorts of strange controller actions. Whilst I am not partial to adding some custom actions here-and-there, I am a firm believer in [keeping your code conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

The above would allow you to call:

```
@conversation = current_user.conversations.find params[:id]
redirect_to user_path(@conversation.recipient_id)
```

---

In regard to your errors, you need to remember that you can call associated objects without having to load fresh instances of classes:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def set_conversation
        if @user 
          @conversation = current_user.conversations.find_by(recipient_id: @user.id)
        end
   end
end
```

Comment: Hey Richard, my controllers must be weird since I have been coding for 2-3 months. At the moment I'm focusing on having stuff that works. On the top of that this is a kinda single page app but without to much JSON at the moment (http://appfaskyn.herokuapp.com) Regarding you suggestion: Can you tell me how this exactly helps me? I don't see how I could put it in my current code. What I guess (likely wrong) is that I should find the user somehow else than User.find(params[:id]) when it comes back from conversations controller. Can't I have just an if else statement or || to find the user?

Answer (score 0):

My comment is within the code.

```
def set_conversation
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) if @user?
    if Task.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?

      #### QUESTION: What will happen if there's no Conversation betwwen the current user 
      #### and the user? What is the returning value of this method? Should you 
      #### redirect it again to user_profile path?

      if Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).present?
        @conversation = Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).first
        @reciever = interlocutor(@conversation)
        @messages = @conversation.messages
        @message = Message.new
        @uploader = @message.mfile
        @uploader.success_action_redirect = messagefilecreation_conversation_url(@conversation.id)
      end
    else
      redirect_to user_profile_path(@user)
    end
  end
```

Comment: There must be at least one task, if you wanna have a conversation with the user. So if you already assigned a task you can continue interacting w/ the user. In case you have created the first task, the conversation will show up if you go the given user's show page. Conversation is created w/ create_or_first method, so there is only one conversation between 2 users.

Comment: it's empty, just this: before_action :set_conversation, only: [:show]

Comment: I have a question for this code

{@user = User.find(params[:id]) if @user?}

Where are the other parts of the code wherein @user is being instantiated or have assigned values?

Comment: Here is everything that is connected to this problem. This if @user was just a silly effort to make things working. This is the only instance for user as all the actions (common tasks w/ the user, chat, file uploading) happen on this page. The problem is that I have to redirect  because of the carrierwave_direct way (I may could use AJAX just don't know how), and then I have to redirect_to :back to the user show page in which case User.find(params[:id]) doesn't work.